# $f^2+(1+f')^2\leq 1 \implies f=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find all $f\in C^1(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ such that $f^2+(1+f')^2\leq 1$

It's quite likely the answer is $f=0$.

Note that $|f|\leq 1$ and $-2\leq f'\leq 0$.

Therefore $f$ is decreasing and bounded.

What then ? I tried contradiction, without success.

Comment: Have you thought about the limits as $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$? Remember that its values are decreasing and lie in a bounded region.

Comment: well $-k\arctan(x)$ with $k$ small enough it seems for me satisfies your condition. Say $-1/\pi$. Then function is from $[-1/2,1/2]$ with negative derivative $>-2$. Something like that.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner with $k=0.01$ it fails at $x=13$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to
$$
f^2+2f'+f'^2\le0\tag{1}
$$
Since $f^2+2f'\le0$, where $f\ne0$, we have
$$
(1/f)'\ge\color{#C00000}{1/2}\tag{2}
$$
If $f(x_0)=a\gt0$, then $\dfrac1f(x_0)=\dfrac1a\gt0$ and $(2)$ says that
$$
\frac1f\left(x_0-\frac3a\right)\le\frac1f(x_0)-\color{#C00000}{\frac12}\frac3a\lt0\tag{3}
$$
as long as $\dfrac1f$ doesn't pass to $-\infty$ in $\left[x_0-\frac3a,x_0\right]$.

In any case, on $\left[x_0-\frac3a,x_0\right]$, $\dfrac1f$ must pass through $0$, which is impossible because $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

If $f(x_0)=a\lt0$, then $\dfrac1f(x_0)=\dfrac1a\lt0$ and $(2)$ says that
$$
\frac1f\left(x_0-\frac3a\right)\ge\frac1f(x_0)-\color{#C00000}{\frac12}\frac3a\gt0\tag{4}
$$
as long as $\dfrac1f$ doesn't pass to $\infty$ in $\left[x_0,x_0-\frac3a\right]$.

In any case, on $\left[x_0,x_0-\frac3a\right]$, $\dfrac1f$ must pass through $0$, which is impossible because $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Therefore, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your argument following $(2)$?

Comment: @AlexSchiff: Any function with a slope at least $\color{#C00000}{1/2}$ (e.g. $1/f$) must pass through the $x$-axis at a finite point.

Comment: What is $f=0$ how you can use (2) then ?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner: $f=0$ satisfies $(1)$. However, $(2)$ obviously holds wherever $f(x)\ne0$.

Comment: Something must be adjusted since $\frac{1}{f}$ is continuous just outside the zeroes of $f$. What happens if a zero of $f$ belongs to the $(x_0-3/a,x_0)$-interval?

Comment: Ok, it cannot happen. Since $f$ is decreasing and $f(x_0)>0$, any zeroes of $f$ is bigger than $x_0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: All that matters is that there is a zero of $1/f$ in the interval. If $f$ has a zero, $1/f$ simply goes to $\infty$. The argument is simply that $1/f$ must pass through $0$ and therefore $f$ must go to $\infty$ in a finite interval, which cannot happen since $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @robjohn: to prove that $1/f$ must pass through zero, you need the continuity of $1/f$ over the whole interval; the argument do not work for continuous function (over their domain) like $\tan x$ in a neighbourhood of $\pi/2$, for example.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: $1/f$ is $C^1$ except where it goes to $\infty$ ($f=0$). From any non-zero value of $1/f$,
 the differential inequality forces $1/f$ to zero in a finite time.

Comment: @robjohn: I completely agree with you, I am simply pointing out that "$\frac{1}{f}$ changes its sign in the endpoints of this interval" does not automatically imply that $\frac{1}{f}$ is zero in an inner point, since $\frac{1}{f}$ can change its sign by passing through a discontinuity, i.e. a zero of $f$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I have edited my answer to account for the case that $1/f$ may blow up inside an interval.

Answer (score 10):

Since $f(x)$ is bounded and decreasing both $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) $ exist. If $f(x)$ were not identically zero, then at least one of these limits is nonzero. Say it is the first one, and call the limit $L$.

By the mean value theorem, $f(n+1) - f(n) = f'(x_n)$ for some $x_n$ between $n$ and $n + 1$. The left-hand side of this equation converges to $L - L = 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity, so we have
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f'(x_n) = 0$$
But we also have
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = L$$
Plugging $x_n$ into $f(x)^2 + (1 + f'(x))^2 \leq 1$ and taking limits as $n$ goes to infinity gives $L^2 \leq 0$, a contradiction.

A similar argument works if $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: This is intuitive, the simplest argument so far.

Comment: And this doesn't use the continuity of the derivative. Nice.

Comment: You don't have to reason by contradiction, because you end up with $L^2 \leq 0 \implies L = 0$ anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Hints: As you mentioned, $f$ is decreasing and bounded. Think about $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$. Must this limit exist? What does this imply for the limit of the derivative $f'$?

**Full Solution.** The function $f(x)$ is decreasing and bounded, so $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=L$ for some $L \in [-1,1]$. For the sake of contradiction, we suppose $|L|>0$. To set up the contradiction, we relate $|f(x)|$ and $f'(x)$:
Let $\epsilon\in (0,1]$, and suppose that we have $0 \geq f'(x) \geq -\epsilon$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{align*}
f^2(x) & \leq 1-(1+f'(x))^2\\
  &\leq -2f'(x) - (f'(x))^2 \\
 &\leq -2f'(x)  \\
 & \leq 2\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Thus $|f(x)| \leq \sqrt{2\epsilon}$. Therefore we know that if $|f(x)| > \sqrt{2\epsilon}$, then $f'(x) <-\epsilon$.
For sufficiently large $x$, we must have $|f(x)| > |L|/2=\sqrt{2(|L|^2/8)}$, hence $f'(x) <-|L|^2/8$. This contradicts the fact that $f(x)$ is bounded below. An entirely analogous argument shows that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=0$. Monotonicity implies $f=0$.**QED**

Comment: Although it should be a cakewalk, I fail to prove that for a $C^1$ function with a limit at infinity, its derivative must have $0$ as limit at $\infty$...

Comment: Have you first shown that the limit of the derivative exists?

Comment: I don't think you can prove the existence of the limit for the derivative with usual theorems. The only information about it is boundedness.

Comment: And now that I remember this, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788813/the-limit-of-the-derivative-of-an-increasing-and-bounded-function-is-always-0/788818#788818 this is definitely wrong.

Comment: I was thinking that the constraint $f^2 +(1-f')^2 \leq 1$ would imply that the derivative's limit existed.

Comment: Another thought would be to compare the limits as $x$ approaches positive and negative infinity. There are some easy restrictions there.

Comment: I found a counterexample function, see my new answer.

Comment: It seems for me your pved only that the fact that $f(x)\to 0$  on infinity. But it does not prove that $f(x)=0$ on $R$. Am I wrong?

Comment: The sequence is decreasing, so that's all that needs to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to completely rewrite the solution keeping the wrong one above untouched. As I said before I am sure we can build such function, and I think I did it using the ODE in the above solution in the end. 
I am building a counterexample function:
Fistly, $f(x)= 0$ for $x\le 0$;

Now I'd like to build a simple function satisfying condition 
$$
f^2+(1+f^\prime)^2\le 1
$$ 
on some interval $[0,x^*]$.
I define 
$$
g(t)=-x^3/3-x^2/2\\
g^\prime(x)=-x^2-x
$$ 
I is obvious that in some positive neighborhood $(0,\epsilon)$
$$
g^2+(1+g^\prime)^2 =O(\epsilon^4)+1-O(\epsilon) \le 1
$$
It is obvious also that staring from some $x^*$ 
$$
g^2+(1+g^\prime)^2\ge 1
$$
Besides we have this point $x^*$ is such that 
$$
g^2(x^*)+(1+g^\prime(x^*))^2= 1
$$
Let's check condition $g^\prime(x^*)>-1$. It is easy t estimate that $x^*$ is about $0.9$ and that then $g^\prime(x^*)< -1

Now again consider the differential equations
$$
f^\prime=-1+\sqrt{1-f^2}\\
f^\prime=-1-\sqrt{1-f^2}\\
$$
and choose the second one  in accordance with the sign $g^\prime(x^*)+1$.
The solution of this equation with initial condition $f(x^*)=g(x^*)$ will extend our function on $R$. 
So the final function $f(x)$ is 
$$
f(x)=0 ~ if ~ x\le 0 \\
f(x)=g(x) ~ if~ 0<x\le x^* \\
solution~ of~ f^\prime=-1-\sqrt{1-f^2}, f(x^*)=g(x^*) ,~ x\ge x*\\
$$

Since I did not find any mistake in the proof that such function cannot exist I again probably made mistake somewhere. But I cannot find it. Any comments please.
May be this ODE cannot have a solution on $R$? Lipschitz condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

FIX
Well the solution of differential equation  with non zero initial condition will satisfy your property
$$
f'=-1-\sqrt{1-f^2}
$$
Edit
Notice that equation 
$$
f'=-1+\sqrt{1-f^2}
$$
is also OK. 
Now let's change $\tau = -t$ and rewrite the second equation as function of $\tau$
$$
f_\tau^\prime =1-\sqrt{1-f^2}
$$
Let's build now the function on $R^+$ as a solution of the first eqaution and on $R^-$ as a solution of the third equation. To guarantee differentiability in $t=0$
let's make equal derivatives at time $t=\tau=0$.
$$
f^\prime_t=-1-\sqrt{1-f^2}=-f^\prime_\tau=-1+\sqrt{1-f^2}
$$
So with initial condition $f=1$ we can propagate this function on $R$.
I changed signs here. Now the initial derivative is

Comment: Can you guarantee that it will exist on all of $\mathbb{R}$ if $f$ is not $\equiv 0$?

Comment: I think we can play a bit with this equation to guarantee this. Let me think

Comment: You can't have $f(x) = 1$ for any $x$. That would imply $f'(x) = -1$, and thus $f(y) > 1$ for $x-\varepsilon < y < x$.

Comment: Who said this. I said it is 1 in the inital point. After this you extend it in both direction via equations.  Extention is built on the different equation it is not symmetric.

Comment: OK. I am wrong about negative direction. But something can be done, I am sure. I don't belieive f=0.

Comment: I'm not sure either way. One could try if something like Gronwall's inequality forces $f\equiv 0$, though.