# Show that it is possible that the limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f'(x)} $ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function with continuous derivative and the limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) }$ exists. Show  with an example that it is possible that the limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f'(x)} $ does not exist.

My attempt:

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{t^2}dt$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \to +\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{t^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) =\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{x^2}= +\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$$

Is my attempt right?

Comment: You've mistaken finding the derivative: for your function $f'(x)=e^{-x^2}$, so limit does exist.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Well, now the integral diverges on both ends!

Comment: Allow me to tell a little story. When I was much younger, I read to my horror in a high-school math text that a differentiable function $f(x)$ has an asymptote for $x \to \infty$ iff $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ exists. Now the examples here show that one implication is not true. The other is disproved by $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$.

Answer (score 7):

Another example, which used to be the *standard* one in my time, is
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \sin( x^{2} ),
$$
where
$$
f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^{2}} \sin(x^{2}
) + \frac{1}{x} 2 x \cos(x^{2})
=
-\frac{1}{x^{2}} \sin(x^{2}
) + 2 \cos(x^{2}).
$$

Comment: will $\frac{1}{x} \sin x$ also work ?

Comment: Nope, $(\sin(x)/x)' = -\sin(x)/x^{2} + \cos(x)/x$ goes to zero as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Nice, thanks...

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Almost right: try $$f(x)=\int_0^x \sin(t^2)\,dt.$$

Comment: So,is my attempt wrong? Why?

Comment: As Ted Shifrin said in the comment to your question, integral of $e^{t^2}$ diverges.

Comment: To elementarily prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists for the above function (without the residue theorem), we can break the integral up into an alternating sum and apply the alternating series test.

Answer (score 1):

Without using integrals, you can consider

- $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$
- $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x}$
- also this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/788818/66096

Answer (score 0):

Any function like
$$ f(x)=x^{-m}\sin(x^n) $$ would work as long as $$ n \gt m $$