# $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exists. $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function.

> If $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = 0$ , then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f^{'}(x) $ exists?

I think the answer is No.

Because I think there may exists function $f$ alternanting its sign as $x \to \infty$.

Could you give me a such function or Prove above statement?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/851342/43949).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the typical example in this case is something like $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x}$. Then by the squeeze theorem we have $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$ but $$f'(x) = \frac{3x^2\cos(x^3)\cdot x - \sin(x^3)}{x^2} = 3x\cos(x^3) + o(1)\,\,\,\,\, \text{ as } x \to \infty$$ so $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: The notation $f \sim g$ is mostly used to mean that $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$, but if $f$ and $g$ do not have the same constant sign after some sufficiently large $x$, we can't conclude that $\lim f(x)$ exists iff $\lim g(x)$ exists. Maybe it would be better to use the notation $\approx$ or something like that

Comment: I use it to mean 'behaves like' in some vague sense. You're right, I could be more precise. I will edit.