# Boundary condition on a function $f(x)$ and its first derivative at $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

If a continuous function $f(x)$ of a real variable $x$ is such that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$, does it necessarily mean that $\frac{df}{dx}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$? If yes, can I prove this?

If not, what is a counter-example where this is not true. The examples, I can think of $\frac{1}{x}, e^{-x}$ etc satisfy this.

Comment: By the way, if you want this to be true, you need the requirement of monotonicity as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: It's still not true with monotonicity @SimpleArt.  See my post.  There's also an explicit construction here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788813/the-limit-of-the-derivative-of-an-increasing-and-bounded-function-is-always-0/788842

Comment: For this to be true you need $f''$ bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, this is not even true if we add a monotonicity hypothesis on the function.  I don't know an explicit formula for this off the top of my head, but consider something like the following:

[image]

Essentially the function is constant between integer-values of its domain, and at each integer value, it takes a steep decline.  The distance the function "drops" at each integer value limits to zero in such a way that we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.  However, because there always *will* be a steep drop at each integer value (albeit arbitrarily small drops), the derivative cannot limit to zero. Note that the "drops" can be smoothed out, say with something [bump-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)-esque, to make $f$ infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Consider the following:

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(e^x)}x$$

as $x\to\pm\infty$, $f(x)\to0$.  However,

$$f'(x)=\frac{xe^x\cos(e^x)-\sin(e^x)}{x^2}\to\text{DNE as }x\to+\infty$$

Here is the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nerjoiput7):

[image]

Comment: very nice example! Do you mind adding a plot of the function to illustrate that the function goes more and more crazy in a smaller and smaller interval (on the y-axis) as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: @Surb Done I do think  :-)

Comment: :) thanks, also if you want the divergence on both sides you might consider $\sin(e^{x^2})/x$

Comment: @Surb True true... taking advantage that all you really need to do is make my function symmetric.

Comment: Actually, the limit isn't $\infty$, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe OOPS!  :D  Should've figured, since I put that graph there >.>