# $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=a$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, infinity

What this means is that if limit $x$ approaches infinity $f(x)$ is a real number other than plus-minus infinity then $f'(x)$ as $x$ approaches infinity will be $0$ or nonexistent. I need mathematical proof or a counterexample.

Comment: Counterexample: $\sin(x^2)/x$

Comment: $\pm \infty$ are not real numbers, so you don't have to specifically exclude them

Comment: Another counterexample $\mathbf 1_{\Bbb Q}(x)/x$

Comment: This is true if $f(x)$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, and differentiable.

Comment: Well, presumably, we are assuming $f(x)$ is differentiable, @HagenvonEitzen :)

Comment: @Crostul thank you I clarified my question because you reminded me of a error I made

Comment: @datboi can you write down a precise meaning for "does not oscillate"?

Comment: @ThomasAndrew That's not true, I've provided a counterexample with strictly increasing, differentiable $f(x)$.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788813/the-limit-of-the-derivative-of-an-increasing-and-bounded-function-is-always-0

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ contain a neighborhood of $+\infty$ and let $f\colon D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be, s.t. $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $+\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=L\in\mathbb{R}$.

For sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the MVT guarantees the existence of $\xi_n\in(n,n+1)$, such that
$$f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{n+1-n}=f^{\prime}(\xi_n).$$
The LHS goes to $L-L=0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so we also have $f^{\prime}(\xi_n)\rightarrow0$. Now **if** $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f^{\prime}(x)\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ exists, it will be equal to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(\xi_n)=0$, because $\xi_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. However, the limit does not need to exist as the counter-example $f\colon(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,x\mapsto\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x}$ shows.

Comment: It's a *huge* assumption to assume $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ exists. That certainly does *not* follow from the hypotheses.

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree it is a huge assumption. It was my interpretation of "does not oscillate", but I was misinterpreting the question. I've edited the answer in a way that complies with OPs latest edit.

Comment: @TedShifrin That huge assumption has been meanwhie edited into the question ("... will be $0$ or nonexistent")

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample:

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}} = g < \infty$.

Let $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-a_n(y-n)^2}\big) dy$.

We have:
 $$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-a_n(x-n)^2} > 0 $$
so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing; we have also
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-a_n(y-n)^2}\big) dy = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a_n}} = g \sqrt{\pi} < \infty$$
However
$$ f'(n) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{-a_m(n-m)^2} \ge e^{-a_n(n-n)^2} = 1$$
so $f'(x)$ does not converge to $0$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Basically, the trick is for $f'(x)$ to be very small most of the time, but on very short intervals it can be arbitrarily big; if the interval is short enough, a big derivative doesn't have to increase $f(x)$ by much.

Comment: How do you explain the answer by @Thorgott? There seems to be a contradiction, since the derivative $f'(n)$ converges to a value for all finite n. Maybe then your function is non-analytic at infinity? How does one reconcile that with the fact that the mean value theorem only requires the existence of the first derivative?

Comment: Thorgott assumes that the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x)$ exists. In my counterexample it does not exist. It's true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f'(n) = 1$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f'(n+\frac12) = 0$, and altogether in my example $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x) $ does not exist.

Comment: thank you, however, your answer is not what I was looking for, I made clarifications to make this clearer.

Comment: In that case, Thorgott's answer is ok. If $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x)$ exists, then indeed $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x)=0$ as Thorgott proves.